# What is the meaning of such definition "#define __arch_swab32 __arch_swab32"?

Tags: c, linux

In /usr/include/asm/swab.h I found following code:

```
static __inline__  __u32 __arch_swab32(__u32 val)
{
    __asm__("bswapl %0" : "=r" (val) : "0" (val));
    return val;
}
#define __arch_swab32 __arch_swab32
```

What is the meaning of the last line, defining a name as itself?

Comment: coupled `#ifdef`?

Comment: maybe to prevent some other code to de-define it without a warning?

Comment: Why this question is primarily opinion based?

Comment: probably someone who doesn't know the answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called [*self-referentitial macro*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/cpp/Self_002dReferential-Macros.html#Self_002dReferential-Macros):

> One common, useful use of self-reference is to create a macro which expands to itself. If you write
>
> ```
>  #define EPERM EPERM
> ```
>
> then the macro `EPERM` expands to `EPERM`. Effectively, it is left alone by the preprocessor whenever it's used in running text. You can tell that it's a macro with `#ifdef`. You might do this if you want to define numeric constants with an `enum`, but have `#ifdef` be true for each constant.

Comment: excellent! you can't tell if a function is defined until you hit the "unresolved symbol" in the linker phase. With ifdef you can know right away!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre; Yes. I am adding another example to explain it a bit more.

Comment: don't overload your answer too much though. Sometimes short is good. I predict you raking a lot of upvotes just like this.